# Have two users challenge each other using reactions discord.py

Tags: discord.py

I would like two users to challenge each other to be able to use reactions so if you can only have one command to use.
Using the command `tfo @user` I would like you to send a private message to the user with the possibility of clicking one of the two reactions to accept or reject the challenge having a time limit that in case it is not executed in time cancels the challenge request and will send another private message (to both of you).

I know that to do this I should use `await client.wait_for` but I don't know how to use it for reactions.

This is the code I used for the version against the bot

```py
@client.command(aliases=["TFO"])
async def tenta_la_fortuna_offline(ctx, amount : int):
    id = str(ctx.message.author.id)
    amounts[id] -= amount
    if amounts[id] < 0:
        await ctx.send(f"Non hai abbastanza soldi per giocare.")
        amounts[id] += amount
        return
    if amount < 99:
        await ctx.send("Puoi puntare da 100 in poi")
        return
    if not amount:
        await ctx.send("Aggiungi quanti soldi vuoi puntare")
        return
    if id not in amounts:
        await ctx.send("Hai bisogno di un account per giocare")
        return
    utente = [
        ('Sei salvo!', 'salvo',),
        ('Sei a rischio eliminazione!', 'rischio',),
        ('Sei __ELIMINATO__!', 'eliminato'),
        ('Hai __~~VINTO~~__!', 'vinto'),
        ('Sei a rischio eliminazione!', 'rischio',),
    ]
    bot = [
        ('Sei salvo!', 'salvo',),
        ('Sei a rischio eliminazione!', 'rischio',),
        ('Sei __ELIMINATO__!', 'eliminato'),
        ('Hai __~~VINTO~~__!', 'vinto'),
        ('Sei a rischio eliminazione!', 'rischio',),
    ]
    embed = discord.Embed(
        title="**Tenta la Fortuna - Offline**",
        description="Affronta il nostro bot per poter vincere il doppio dei soldi scommessi!",
        color=0x003399
    )
    embed.set_thumbnail(url='https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/640563710104043530/731596857868025886/TENTA_LA_FORTUNA.png')
    embed.add_field(
        name="**Utente**",
        value="** **",
        inline=True
    )
    embed.add_field(
        name="**Bot**",
        value="** **",
        inline=True
    )
    message = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    win = int(amount * 2)
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    for numero in range(1,101):
        u_uscita, u_condizione = random.choice(utente)
        embed.clear_fields()
        if u_condizione == "eliminato":
            embed = discord.Embed(
                title="**Tenta la Fortuna - Offline**",
                description="Affronta il nostro bot per poter vincere il doppio dei soldi scommessi!",
                color=0xFF0000
            )
            embed.set_thumbnail(
                url='https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/640563710104043530/731596857868025886/TENTA_LA_FORTUNA.png'
            )
            embed.set_footer(
                text=f"Round numero {numero}"
            )
            embed.add_field(
                name="**Utente**",
                value=f"{u_uscita}",
                inline=True
            )
            embed.add_field(
                name="**Bot**",
                value="** **",
                inline=True
            )
            await message.edit(embed=embed)
            return
        if u_condizione == "vinto":
            embed = discord.Embed(
                title="**Tenta la Fortuna - Offline**",
                description="Affronta il nostro bot per poter vincere il doppio dei soldi scommessi!",
                color=0x00FF00
            )
            embed.set_thumbnail(
                url='https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/640563710104043530/731596857868025886/TENTA_LA_FORTUNA.png'
            )
            embed.set_footer(
                text=f"Round numero {numero}"
            )
            embed.add_field(
                name="**Utente**",
                value=f"{u_uscita}",
                inline=True
            )
            embed.add_field(
                name="**Bot**",
                value="** **",
                inline=True
            )
            await message.edit(embed=embed)
            amounts[id] += win
            return
        embed.set_footer(
            text=f"Round numero {numero}"
        )
        embed.add_field(
            name="**Utente**",
            value=f"{u_uscita}",
            inline=True
        )
        embed.add_field(
            name="**Bot**",
            value="** **",
            inline=True
        )
        await message.edit(embed=embed)
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
        b_uscita, b_condizione = random.choice(bot)
        embed.clear_fields()
        if b_condizione == "vinto":
            embed = discord.Embed(
                title="**Tenta la Fortuna - Offline**",
                description="Affronta il nostro bot per poter vincere il doppio dei soldi scommessi!",
                color=0xFF0000
            )
            embed.set_thumbnail(
                url='https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/640563710104043530/731596857868025886/TENTA_LA_FORTUNA.png'
            )
            embed.set_footer(
                text=f"Round numero {numero}"
            )
            embed.add_field(
                name="**Utente**",
                value=f"{u_uscita}",
                inline=True
            )
            embed.add_field(
                name="**Bot**",
                value=f"{b_uscita}",
                inline=True
            )
            await message.edit(embed=embed)
            return
        if u_condizione == "rischio":
            if b_condizione == "salvo":
                embed = discord.Embed(
                    title="**Tenta la Fortuna - Offline**",
                    description="Affronta il nostro bot per poter vincere il doppio dei soldi scommessi!",
                    color=0xFF0000
                )
                embed.set_thumbnail(
                    url='https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/640563710104043530/731596857868025886/TENTA_LA_FORTUNA.png'
                )
                embed.set_footer(
                    text=f"Round numero {numero}"
                )
                embed.add_field(
                    name="**Utente**",
                    value=f"{u_uscita}",
                    inline=True
                )
                embed.add_field(
                    name="**Bot**",
                    value=f"{b_uscita}",
                    inline=True
                )
                await message.edit(embed=embed)
                return
        if b_condizione == "eliminato":
            embed = discord.Embed(
                title="**Tenta la Fortuna - Offline**",
                description="Affronta il nostro bot per poter vincere il doppio dei soldi scommessi!",
                color=0x00FF00
            )
            embed.set_thumbnail(
                url='https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/640563710104043530/731596857868025886/TENTA_LA_FORTUNA.png'
            )
            embed.set_footer(
                text=f"Round numero {numero}"
            )
            embed.add_field(
                name="**Utente**",
                value=f"{u_uscita}",
                inline=True
            )
            embed.add_field(
                name="**Bot**",
                value=f"{b_uscita}",
                inline=True
            )
            await message.edit(embed=embed)
            amounts[id] += amount
            return
        if b_condizione == "rischio":
            if u_condizione == "salvo":
                embed = discord.Embed(
                    title="**Tenta la Fortuna - Offline**",
                    description="Affronta il nostro bot per poter vincere il doppio dei soldi scommessi!",
                    color=0x00FF00
                )
                embed.set_thumbnail(
                    url='https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/640563710104043530/731596857868025886/TENTA_LA_FORTUNA.png'
                )
                embed.set_footer(
                    text=f"Round numero {numero}"
                )
                embed.add_field(
                    name="**Utente**",
                    value=f"{u_uscita}",
                    inline=True
                )
                embed.add_field(
                    name="**Bot**",
                    value=f"{b_uscita}",
                    inline=True
                )
                await message.edit(embed=embed)
                amounts[id] += win
                return
        embed.set_footer(
            text=f"Round numero {numero}"
        )
        embed.add_field(
            name="**Utente**",
            value=f"{u_uscita}",
            inline=True
        )
        embed.add_field(
            name="**Bot**",
            value=f"{b_uscita}",
            inline=True
        )
        await message.edit(embed=embed)
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        if numero == 100:
            embed = discord.Embed(
                title="**Tenta la Fortuna - Offline**",
                description="Affronta il nostro bot per poter vincere il doppio dei soldi scommessi!",
                color=0xDBA901
            )
            embed.set_thumbnail(
                url='https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/640563710104043530/731596857868025886/TENTA_LA_FORTUNA.png'
            )
            embed.set_footer(
                text=f"Round numero {numero}"
            )
            embed.add_field(
                name="**Utente**",
                value=f"{u_uscita}",
                inline=True
            )
            embed.add_field(
                name="**Bot**",
                value=f"{b_uscita}",
                inline=True
            )
            await message.edit(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code fragment is huge & in another language so I can't help you directly (as I have no idea what's going on), but this is how to use `wait_for` with reactions:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('$thumb'):
        channel = message.channel
        await channel.send('Send me that  reaction, mate')

        def check(reaction, user):
            return user == message.author and str(reaction.emoji) == ''

        try:
            reaction, user = await client.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=60.0, check=check)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await channel.send('')
        else:
            await channel.send('')
```

Fragment taken out of the `API Docs` for `wait_for`, shows how to wait for a  reaction & do something with it. In case the user doesn't add the reaction within the `timeout` (here 60 seconds), it will throw a `TimeoutError` and send . You can modify this to fit your needs & put it in your command where it fits.

Comment: Hello.
How could I apply these strings in a command? I understand the system but I don't know how to apply it and how to specify that only if the author of the message reacts to go ahead.

Comment: Hi, I'm still trying to use this method that at the moment when it must work but I would like that when the reaction is added the user's reaction is also deleted. I tried with `ctx.author` and failed, are there any other methods?

Comment: ``I don't know how to specify that only if the author of the message reacts to go ahead"`` This is literally in the example above, the ``check`` function checks if the person that added the reaction (``user``) is the same on as the author (``message.author``)

Comment: ``How could I apply these strings in a command?`` Take everything below the first if-statement (ignore the `if message.content.startswith()`, that's what your command does),  and replace `message` with `ctx`.

Comment: What do you mean with "I tried and failed"? Can you update your post to show what you tried & say what went wrong? Just saying "it failed" isn't very helpful for me to help you out. Also, please only post the relevant part of the code, not something huge like in the original post.

Comment: I update you:
message.author was causing me problems since I needed ctx.author. I couldn't remove the reactions because I wanted to apply it to private messages. In the end I tried and it works but take an example using also the command and not the event otherwise it is confusing.

Comment: `ctx.author` and `message.author` are the same thing, that shouldn't be causing you any issues. The only difference is the name of the variable.